# Looping through all characters in a string element of a string vector in C++

Tags: c++, string, loops, vector, stl

Say, for example I have a vector. The vector contains i items. Say I want to loop through all positions j in every element i of the vector. I attempt to use a nested for loop to perform the procedure in the following code. It attempts to change every element to all ks, like so:

```
vector<string> strvec;
strvec.push_back("Dog");
strvec.push_back("Cat");

for (int i = 0; i < strvec.length; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < strvec[i].length; j++)
    {
        strvec[i][j] = 'k';
    }
}
```

Whenever using the loop in this manner, the above code will get error messages, even before the code in the nested loop (starting at the beginning of the nested loop). Is there a way to loop through every character in every element of a string vector that is effective and that works?

Comment: If it gets "error messages" then *please* add those to the question.

Comment: Consider `strvec.size()` in place of `strvec.length`

Comment: Another thing: [Range based `for` loops](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for) are awesome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an approach that uses references and range-based `for`. Any time you have to iterate a container starting at the beginning, try range-based `for` first. It's not as versatile as manual control, but it is really, really hard to get wrong.

```
for (string & str: strvec)
{
    for (char & ch: str)
    {
        ch = 'k';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`std::vector` has a `size` function you can use for iteration:

```
for (std::size_t i = 0; i < strvec.size(); i++)
{
    for (std::size_t j = 0; j < strvec[i].size(); j++)
    {
        strvec[i][j] = 'k';
    }
}
```

Comment: I am not seeing `length` as a member of `vector` in the reference I use. But I recognize your name and am inclined to defer to you.

Comment: Vector does not have a `length` function, it has `size`.

Comment: You are correct. The edited code (not my edits) is much better.